# Form Confirmation message ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

stmaybe tired, but I can't do what I want.

I'd like a confirmation text saying like "Thanks for sumbitting this form" after the user clicked on the submit button (then sent to my e-mail). It's a one page website.
I know I have to use a bit of jQuery, a bit of ajax (for not reloading the page right?) and my php script for the form ; to send values filled in the form to my e-mail. (<- working)

Any help? I already got another form and it's working too. but confirmation message not needed there.

This is what I got so far but not seems to work..

**At the top of my index.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitReserv'])){

        $sujet = 'stuff - reservation';
        $monEmail = 'email@email.com'; <- my mail
        $headers ='From: '.$reservNom.'<email@email.com>';

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $message.=$key.' -> '.$value.'
';

 }

if(isset($_POST['lieu'])) 
 { 
       echo htmlentities($_POST['lieu']); 
 } 
if(isset($_POST['ambiance'])) 
 { 
       echo htmlentities($_POST['ambiance']); 
 } 
 if(isset($_POST['menu'])) 
 { 
       echo htmlentities($_POST['menu']); 
 } 


    // ini_set('sendmail_from', $email); 
    mail($monEmail, $sujet, $message, $headers);


}

?>
```

**My all div for the form**

```
<div id="form-reserv" class="page">

<div class="container">

    <!-- Title Page -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="title-page">
                <h2 class="title">Réservations</h2>
                <h3 class="title-description">Reservez sur internet vos <a href="#">dates</a>.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Title Page -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <form id="reserv-form" class="nl-form contact-form" method="post">
                <p>J'aimerais manger au/à 
                <select name="lieux">
                    <option value="null" selected>(cliquez ici)</option>
                    <option value="Parc">PdC</option>
                    <option value="Mont">MdA</option>
                    <option value="GP">GP</option>
                </select></p>
                <p>avec l'ambiance
                <select name="ambiance">
                    <option value="null" selected>(cliquez ici)</option>
                    <option value="Paradise">Paradise</option>
                    <option value="Heat">Heat</option>
                    <option value="Nature">Nature</option>

                </select></p>
                <p>et le menu
                <select name="menu">
                    <option value="null" selected>(cliquez ici)</option>
                    <option value="MP">Manneken Pies</option>
                    <option value="Atomnium">Atomnium</option>
                    <option value="Horta">Horta</option>
                </select></p>

            <br/>

                <p class="contact-name">
                    <input id="reservNom" type="text" placeholder="Votre nom" value="" name="reservNom" />
                </p>
                 <p class="contact-name">
                    <input id="reservPrenom" type="text" placeholder="Votre Prénom" value="" name="reservPrenom" />
                </p>
                <p class="contact-email">
                    <input id="reservEmail" type="text" placeholder="Votre E-mail" value="" name="reservEmail" />
                </p>
                <p class="contact-name">
                    <input id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre de personnes (Maximum 4 personnes)" max="4" name="nombre" />
                </p>
                <p class="contact-name">
                    <input id="date" type="date" placeholder="Format : JJ/MM/AAAA" step="6"/>
                </p>
                <p><input value="RESERVEZ" class="submit" id="submitReserv" name="submitReserv" type="submit">
                 </p>

                   <div id="response">
                    </div

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

So, what am i suppose to write more and where? What is still needed, is to have this confirmation text. I got a main.js in my _includes/js directory..
Sorry, i'm not so good with js and ajax for now.. 
I'd appreciate you help me out!
Thanks guys!

---

EDIT - That is for another form in my one page that works.. but for not the one i have.

```
BRUSHED.contactForm = function(){
$("#contact-submit").on('click',function() {
    $contact_form = $('#contact-form');

    var fields = $contact_form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_include/php/contact.php",
        data: fields,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

            if(response.status){
                $('#contact-form input').val('');
                $('#contact-form textarea').val('');
            }

            $('#response').empty().html(response.html);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

}

Comment: Can you please post what javascript you have currently?

Comment: Nothing for this form actually.. (otherwise bunch of js files like fancybox,isotope and stuff).  Thing is i have now another form where the thing i want to do works. 

I edited my Original Post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use very simple javascript confirm box like this on your submit button

```
<p><input value="RESERVEZ" class="submit" id="submitReserv" name="submitReserv" type="submit" onClick="if(!confirm('Thanks for sumbitting this form')){ return false; }">
             </p>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks,it works, but i want a text  that show up into a div below the </form>.
So once completed and clicked, the text shows and say "Thanks blabla"

Comment: Ideally its not good practice to add confirmation box below form. Meaning of using confirmation message is to keep users complete focus on that confirmation message, because system will not proceed until it recives users feedback whether to confirm or not. Still if you want you need to create some javascript function and hide and show div below your form.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is provide a message when the submission returns successful then you already have your answer. You can do everything you want in the success callback in your $.ajax() call. Here is a simplified version of your js that should do what you want

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: //your url here,
    data: fields,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {

        $('#reserv-form').parent().append("<div>Thanks for submitting this form</div>")
    }
  });
```

Comment: If i want this code in another .js file, what am I suppose to write first at the top? Thanks... sorry beeing beginner :(

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ //your code here }

You should also probably wrap the ajax in some sort of binding function like you did with #contract-submit

Comment: What should i wrote in " url : //your url here " ?
just url : "index.php" ? 
(thx so much for ur help)

Comment: I honestly can't say, it should be the url that will handle your post request. Since you are using PHP it will likely be whatever page that will be handling the post request.